# C++ Qt How to Create a Duplicate of a GUI with small changes

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, cmake

I have a GUI called UINode and I want to create a duplicate and change only a few things.
The project is made of 3 basic threads. PingThread,RosThread and the GuiThread. I tried to copy-paste the project folder and rename it to UINode2 but it gives me errors when i try to compile it using catkin_make. 
I'm pretty sure this are errors caused by the identical headers.

**Error:**

```
CMakeFiles/drone_gui2.dir/src/UINode/moc_tum_ardrone_gui.cxx.o:moc_tum_ardrone_gui.cxx:(.text+0x0): first defined here CMakeFiles/drone_gui2.dir/src/UINode2/moc_tum_ardrone_gui.cxx.o:(.rodata+0x100): multiple definition of `tum_ardrone_gui::staticMetaObject' CMakeFiles/drone_gui2.dir/src/UINode/moc_tum_ardrone_gui.cxx.o:(.rodata+0x100): first defined here CMakeFiles/drone_gui2.dir/src/UINode2/moc_tum_ardrone_gui.cxx.o: In function `tum_ardrone_gui::qt_metacast(char const*)': moc_tum_ardrone_gui.cxx:(.text+0x20): multiple definition of `tum_ardrone_gui::qt_metacast(char const*)' CMakeFiles/drone_gui2.dir/src/UINode/moc_tum_ardrone_gui.cxx.o:moc_tum_ardrone_gui.cxx:(.text+0x20): first defined here CMakeFiles/drone_gui2.dir/src/UINode2/moc_tum_ardrone_gui.cxx.o: In function `tum_ardrone_gui::qt_static_metacall(QObject*, QMetaObject::Call, int, void**)': moc_tum_ardrone_gui.cxx:(.text+0x70): multiple definition of `tum_ardrone_gui::qt_static_metacall(QObject*, QMetaObject::Call, int, void**)' CMakeFiles/drone_gui2.dir/src/UINode/moc_tum_ardrone_gui.cxx.o:moc_tum_ardrone_gui.cxx:(.text+0x70): first defined here CMakeFiles/drone_gui2.dir/src/UINode2/moc_tum_ardrone_gui.cxx.o: In function `tum_ardrone_gui::qt_metacall(QMetaObject::Call, int, void**)': moc_tum_ardrone_gui.cxx:(.text+0x6f0): multiple definition of `tum_ardrone_gui::qt_metacall(QMetaObject::Call, int, void**)' CMakeFiles/drone_gui2.dir/src/UINode/moc_tum_ardrone_gui.cxx.o:moc_tum_ardrone_gui.cxx:(.text+0x6f0): first defined here
```

**Code:**

```
#include "tum_ardrone_gui.h"
#include "RosThread.h"
#include "PingThread.h"

#include <QtGui>
#include <QApplication>
#include "ros/ros.h"

// this global var is used in getMS(ros::Time t) to convert to a consistent integer timestamp used internally pretty much everywhere.
// kind of an artifact from Windows-Version, where only that was available / used.
unsigned int ros_header_timestamp_base = 0;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::cout << "Starting drone_gui Node" << std::endl;

    // ROS
    ros::init(argc, argv, "drone_gui");

    RosThread t;
    PingThread p;

    // UI
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    tum_ardrone_gui w;

    // make them communicate with each other
    t.gui = &w;
    w.rosThread = &t;
    p.gui = &w;
    p.rosThread = &t;
    w.pingThread = &p;

    // start them.
    t.startSystem();
    p.startSystem();
    w.show();

    // wait until windows closed....
    int ec = a.exec();

     // stop ROS again....
    t.stopSystem();
    p.stopSystem();

    std::cout << "Exiting drone_gui Node" << std::endl;

    return ec;
}
```

My question is: Imagine I want to replicate my UINode 10 times. Do I need to hardcode my code and make changes to every thread name, class,etc... or there is a better way?

Comment: are you doing different projects or do you want to make those different nodes in the same project?

Comment: They need to be different projects (I think) because I need to change the path of each node that they will subscribe and publish (Robot1 and Robot2). But I want to compile them and run at the same time to control Robot1 with UINode and Robot2 with UINode2.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'path of each node'? On the file system? Could you pass these to your application via command line parameters? Then you only would have to evaluate these, not having to create any additional application at all...

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to collect all code that is common within a separate project and build it as a library (static or shared). It might be convenient to implement the differences as polymorphism, so you have base classes in the library and implement or override behaviour in sub classes of the specific projects.

This way, you only implement the differences in each project and link all of them to the library containing the common code.

**Edit:**

Perhaps all this is not necessary: Have you thought of controlling different behaviour in each instance of your application via command line parameters?

Imagine you have a TCP client for whatever purpose. Would you recompile it for usage with each new host you want to communicate with? Certainly not. Instead, you would pass the host address as parameters, e. g. -h 127.0.0.1 -p 1977 or -h 127.0.0.1:1977.

Comment: I'm a begineer :D Can you simplify?

Comment: Libraries are designed to share one and the same code across different executables. Their advantage is that they are compiled once, and you can include this already finished code into any number of applications (technically correct: you link against them). Have you ever noticed the -l option of gcc (I think it is the same for msvc). With this option, you tell the compiler that it shall use (link against) already compiled code that is provided in a library, for instance if you are building a QT GUI application.

Comment: I agree. This is what is called refactoring. Polymorphism is however not the only way to achieve that.

Comment: @user2672165 I agree, too. There are always many ways to achieve a specific goal ("all roads leading to Rome"). Polymorphism often is convenient, in other situations, your breaking your head trying to achieve it with brute force...